# Excel formula question, if the number is the same, then add a 1-9, if not, dont

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a noobie at excel and tried to find the answer to my question without success.
I have a list with 10 000 rows of employment numbers, containing different employment periods.

I have [Employment Number] in B2, and if the number is in B3, then i want to add [Employment Number]-2.
If the next row contains the same number, then [Employment Number]-3.
If the next row DOESNT contain the same number, then [Employment Number].

I hope that you understand my question, if not, let me know.
I think i have the latest version of excel.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data plus your expected outcome. E.g. it should be clear whether the Employment numbers are sorted or not?

Comment: As per @ike, it's probably good to know if data is sorted, but if as per your query then try `=IF(B2=B1,B2&"-"&COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B2),B2)`

Comment: @JvdV you solved the issue, thanks for the feedback :)